# Sql UDF Optimization

Tags: sql-server, function, query-optimization

I have written the following function that takes in two strings (comma-separated), splits them into two different temp tables and then uses those temp tables to find what percentage of words match in those two temp tables. The problem is that when I am using it per row basis on a data set of about 200k rows, the query times out! 
Are there any optimizations that you can see that can be done?

```
ALTER FUNCTION [GetWordSimilarity](@String varchar(8000), 
@String2 varchar(8000),@Delimiter char(1))
returns decimal(16,2)        
as        
begin        
declare @result as decimal (16,2)
declare @temptable table (items varchar(8000))        
declare @temptable2 table (items varchar(8000))  
declare @numberOfCommonWords decimal(16,2)
declare @countTable1 decimal(16,2)
declare @countTable2 decimal(16,2)
declare @denominator decimal(16,2)
set @result = 0.0 --dummy value
declare @idx int        
declare @slice varchar(8000)        

select @idx = 1        
    if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  or len(@String2) = 0 or @String2 is null return 0.0

--populating @temptable
while @idx!= 0        
begin        
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)        
    if @idx!=0        
       set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)
    else        
        set @slice = @String

    if(len(@slice)>0)   
        insert into @temptable(Items) values(ltrim(rtrim(@slice)))        

    set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)        
    if len(@String) = 0 break        
end    

select @idx = 1

----populating @temptable2
while @idx!= 0        
begin        
    set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String2)        
    if @idx!=0        
       set @slice = left(@String2,@idx - 1)
    else        
        set @slice = @String2

    if(len(@slice)>0)   
        insert into @temptable2(Items) values(ltrim(rtrim(@slice)))        

    set @String2 = right(@String2,len(@String2) - @idx)        
    if len(@String2) = 0 break        
end    

--calculating percentage of words match
if (((select COUNT(*) from @temptable) = 0) or ((select COUNT(*) from @temptable2) = 0))
    return 0.0

select @numberOfCommonWords = COUNT(*) from 
(
    select distinct items from @temptable
    intersect
    select distinct items from @temptable2
) a

select @countTable1 = COUNT (*) from @temptable
select @countTable2 = COUNT (*) from @temptable2

if(@countTable1 > @countTable2) set @denominator = @countTable1
else set @denominator = @countTable2

set @result = @numberOfCommonWords/@denominator

return @result
end
```

Thanks a bunch !

Comment: you could optimize the splitting using a number table.  there is an example on sqlcentral and explanation on how it works.  I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Thank you! Please let me know if you can find it. Thanks again!

Comment: I found the link http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/  Essentialy you make a table with numbers and use that to perform the loop.  The article is way to long for on here.

Comment: If anybody would be willing to give it a go you can find some test-data generating code here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/51453/1

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to write a T SQL UDF with heavy string manipulation inside that will behave OK on large number of rows. You will get some gain if you use the Numbers table, though:

```
declare 
    @col_list varchar(1000),
    @sep char(1)

set @col_list = 'TransactionID, ProductID, ReferenceOrderID, ReferenceOrderLineID, TransactionDate, TransactionType, Quantity, ActualCost, ModifiedDate'
set @sep = ','

select substring(@col_list, n, charindex(@sep, @col_list + @sep, n) - n)
from numbers where substring(@sep + @col_list, n, 1) = @sep
and n < len(@col_list) + 1
```

Your best course of action would be to write the whole thing in SQLCLR.

Comment: How would SQLCLR help?

Comment: The string manipulation functions in .NET Framework are much faster that T SQL counterparts.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of course is with the design. You shouldn't be storing comma-separated data in a SQL database to start with.
But, I guess we're stuck with it for now.
One thing to consider is converting the function to SQLCLR; SQL by itself is not very good with string operations. (Well, in fact, no language is good with string operations IMHO but SQL really is bad at it =)

The splitter you use to fill @Temptables 1 & 2 can be optimized by using the code from Jeff Moden who wrote several fantastic articles of which the last one can be found here : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Taking his splitter + optimizing the rest of the code a bit I managed to get from 771 seconds to 305 seconds on a 200K random data sample.
Some things to note: the results aren't quite the same. I checked some manually and I actually think the new results are more accurate but don't really have time to go bughunting on both versions.

I tried to convert this to a more set-based approach where I first load all the words in a table that has all words for all row_id's and then join them back together. Although the joining is quite fast, it simply takes too long to create the initial tables so it even loses out on the original function.

Maybe I'll try to figure out another way to make it faster but for now I hope this will help you out a bit.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [GetWordSimilarity2](@String1 varchar(8000), 
@String2 varchar(8000),@Delimiter char(1))
returns decimal(16,2)        
as        
begin        
declare @temptable1 table (items varchar(8000), row_id int IDENTITY(1, 1), PRIMARY KEY (items, row_id))        
declare @temptable2 table (items varchar(8000), row_id int IDENTITY(1, 1), PRIMARY KEY (items, row_id))   
declare @numberOfCommonWords decimal(16,2)
declare @countTable1 decimal(16,2)
declare @countTable2 decimal(16,2)

-- based on code from Jeff Moden (http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)

--populating @temptable1
 ;WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@String1),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@String1,t.N,1) = @Delimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String1,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
INSERT @temptable1 (items)
 SELECT Item       = SUBSTRING(@String1, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l

SELECT @countTable1 = @@ROWCOUNT

----populating @temptable2
 ;WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@String2),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@String2,t.N,1) = @Delimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String2,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
INSERT @temptable2 (items)
 SELECT Item       = SUBSTRING(@String2, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l

SELECT @countTable2 = @@ROWCOUNT

--calculating percentage of words match
if @countTable1 = 0 OR @countTable2 = 0
    return 0.0

select @numberOfCommonWords = COUNT(DISTINCT t1.items) 
    from @temptable1 t1
    JOIN @temptable2 t2
    ON t1.items = t2.items


RETURN @numberOfCommonWords / (CASE WHEN (@countTable1 > @countTable2) THEN @countTable1 ELSE @countTable2 END)

end
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation! I am testing various versions of the function now (including Sql CLR). Will let you know as soon as I am done. Thanks again :)